# Erro em posicionamento de divs

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma página, que possui três `divs`. A primeira contém um banner gerenciável a segunda tem uma imagem de fundo e a terceira é uma cor chapada.
Como mostra a imagem abaixo:
[image: layout]

Minha dúvida é: o banner um, tem tipo um corte e o dois também, no caso irei usar um JPG. porém, como as divs são quadrada por padrão, terei de usar `position` e `z-index`.

Meu código atual está assim http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/87L7r2nx/

O que acontece, é que quando eu chego na div três, colocando `position` e `z-index`, só que não aparece.

O que está errado?

Comment: O código no JSFiddle tem muita coisa, está difícil identificar o elemento `1`, `2` e `3` para ajudar a resolver o problema. Dá para referenciar quem é quem?

Comment: atualizei agora, veja se está melhor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analise

Já estive a olhar para o código [no teu JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/87L7r2nx/). O problema parece ser a organização do elementos para que a *stack* funcione da maneira que pretendes.

O que sugiro é utilizares uma estrutura simples e após isso ires formatando consoante a necessidade:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="imagem1"> </div>
  <div class="imagem2"> </div>
  <div class="corSolida"> </div>
</div>
```

No elemento `#wrapper` dás um `position:relative;` e aos elementos filhos um `position:absolute;`. Desta forma podes manipular a posição dos três elementos para chegares à composição pretendida.

De igual forma também consegues ajustar a posição do elemento `#wrapper` e se necessário dar-lhe posição absoluta e chegar o mesmo para baixo.

Da forma que tens atualmente, os elementos posicionados de forma absoluta estão relativos à tab `body`. Como tens dois elementos no topo (`topoBarra` e `topoMenu`) já a ocuparem determinado espaço, as coordenadas de posicionamento absoluto começam após o espaço ocupado pelos referidos elementos, isto porque tens o posicionamento absoluto a ser dados a elementos filhos que por si são elementos filhos da tag `body`. (é confuso, eu sei...).

## Solução

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Lfb3gv8e/)

### HTML

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="indawo eyodwa">1</div>
    <div class="indawo ezimbili">2</div>
    <div class="indawo amathathu">3</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}

/* Elemento chave para criar a área de manipulação */
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
}

/* definições comuns aos três elementos a manipular
 */
.indawo{
    position:absolute;
    background:none no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* primeiro elemento posicionado absolutamente, com coordenada de topo
 * a 0 (zero) para ficar colado ao topo do elemento #wrapper
 */
.eyodwa{
    top:0px;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WwA2.png);
    overflow: hidden;
    width:592px;
    height:242px;
}

/* segundo elemento posicionado absolutamente, com coordenada de topo
 * para o "chegar para baixo" o suficiente para alinhar as imagens
 */
.ezimbili{
    top:105px;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFCc9.png);
    overflow: hidden;
    width:592px;
    height:213px;
}

/* terceiro elemento posicionado absolutamente, com coordenada de topo
 * para o "chegar para baixo" o suficiente para ter as imagens do primeiro
 * e segundo elemento visiveis por completo.
 */
.amathathu{
    top:318px;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:592px;
    height:200px;
}
```

### Pré-visualização

Na pré-visualização estou a selecionar os elementos usando o inspetor do navegador para os destacar. Podes ver que os dois elementos onde ficam as duas imagens estão sobrepostos. O terceiro elemento fica por baixo deles.

[image: Simulação de seleção dos elementos com o inspetor do navegador]

<sup>Cada frame dura 2 segundos.</sup>

Comment: Entendi, eu estava tendo problemas com o posicionamento, como eu havia suspeitado. No caso, todos irão se basear pelo `#wrapper`, e o que devo mudar mesmo é o `top`.